# How to write to a text file the output of for loop, which collects data from multiple URL similar pages?

Tags: python, html, request

I collect data from multiple URL similar pages using a loop for every element. (it works)
printing the results. (it works)

Instead of printing, I want to write the results inside one text file. every time the loop collect new page.

```
    reference = (
    "TY  - THES", 
    "AB  - " + abstract1_1, 
    "AU  - " + author1_1, 
    "DO  - " + uri1_1,
    "T1  - " + title1_1, 
    "UR  - " + url,
    "ER  - ",
    "             ")

    print(reference)# print works coerctly but I can write inside Refs.txt

    myfile = open('Refs.txt', 'w')
    myfile.write('\n%s' % i for i in reference)
    myfile.close()
```

Comment: Where is the geospatial  component of the question ?

Comment: @gene Some respect to the beginners, everyone was a beginner..

Comment: It is not a question of respect but questions with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here but can be researched/asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: python, beautyfulsoup

Comment: Without a Gis component, unfortunately .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('Refs.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in reference:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: thank you, But, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python\Python-FilePy-Thesis-DownLoad\Thesis-UTexas-Ruthenium-Link-319R-ListOfLinks_Done2_write.py", line 73, in <module>
    f.write(line)
  File "C:\Users\mzain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2083' in position 863: character maps to <undefined>
PS F:\Python>

Comment: might need to add encoding, see edit `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: Where I should add encoding='utf-8' ?